# How to see Java executable jar file now running and stop jar file from GUI or notification window?

Tags: java, swing, executable-jar, httpserver

I have **Java Basic HTTP server** running on localhost:9090 and listening request coming it. This Java application is a **executable jar** file.I am running the jar file by double clicking. My Java application (jar) has no GUI and no need GUI.

But I couldn't understand executable jar file is started and running when I clicked double. I can find the process running the executable jar when I check the processes running on the machine, of course.

A user working with executable jar may not find this process. Because not everyone is a developer. It is also not a user friendly.

I would like to let you know that jar is running with a notification to the user who double-clicked the executable jar file.

This can be a window, or windows can receive notification right at the bottom.
If the user wants, it can stop the operation of the jar by pressing the button in this window.

I want something simple.
Logically remember the xamp server. the user should be able to see if the jar is really working by clicking the notifications right below.

As I said, the app does not need to have written a GUI but it can be a small interface.

How can I handle this job?

Comment: Create a .bat or a .sh file with java -jar myJar.jar command. Double click on this script. Then the terminal is a kind of "console".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write another small java app, which will run this one and provide system-tray functionality. AWT has some systemtray functionality, which is better (when I played with it) than swing systemtray functionality. And there is even some projects to offer even better solution: https://github.com/dorkbox/SystemTray

But there's probably no way how to fix current application without doing any coding.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a icon to the system tray: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/systemtray.html

Or the easiest one would be to start your application in a separate thread, then you could open a JOptionPane which stops the application thread when the dialog have been closed. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html

Note, a JOptionPane is a simple dialog with no application icon in the taskbar. If you would like to have your application in the taskbar, you have to create a window.